# How to connect MPLAB with mikroICD?

Tags: debugger

How can I connect the MPLAB software from MicroChip with my mikroICD debugger so I can flash and debug my assembler programs?

Comment: IF you don't get any answers here, try asking at [electronics](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/) site.

Comment: I followed your advice and posted the question there.

Comment: *update* they don't accept my question at the electronics site..

Comment: Interesting. I'm user at both sites and questions related to equipment and specific software were allowed there. Anyway it took me a while to connect mikroICD with mikroElektronika. You could try asking their [support](http://www.mikroe.com/esupport/) for help. They removed BigPic 5 from the site, but if my memory serves me correctly, you might be out of luck. I think that back when BigPic 5 was new, mikroE tried to push its own closed system on the board users and as a result of that I think that Big Pic 5 doesn't support MPLAB.